# Not able to receive the data from the Machine Using TCP/IP Socket in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, ascii, tcplistener

I have a machine which i am trying to connect using TCP/IP by passing Username and Password.

This is the username and password as per the machine documentation..

```
By default, the Panasonic NCP/TDE system requires a username/password (default:SMDR/PCCSMDR) to connect to the TCP/IP feed.
```

But I am not able to get the data from the machine into the text file.Instead of the correct data i am getting following data into the text file..

```
-

S

MDR

/PCCSMD

RSMDR

/PC

CSMDR
```

This data is getting dumped into the text file continuously.Here is my code in  c#

```
        ipaddress = "192.168.1.230";
        int port = int.Parse("2300");
        textfileSaveLocation = "D://vikas//call.txt";

        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        string stringData;
        string input;

            IPAddress ipadd = IPAddress.Parse(ipaddress);
            IPEndPoint ipend = new IPEndPoint(ipadd,port);
            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            sock.NoDelay = false;
            try
            {
                sock.Connect(ipend);
                textBox4.AppendText("Connected to host" + "\r\n");
            }
            catch (Exception dfg)
            {
                textBox4.AppendText("Problem connecting to host" + "\r\n");
                textBox4.AppendText(dfg.ToString ()+"\r\n");
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                int recv = sock.Receive(data);
                stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
                textBox4.AppendText(stringData + "\r\n");
                while (true)
                {
                    Byte[] bBuf;
                    string buf;

                    Application.DoEvents();

                    buf = String.Format("{0}/{1}", "SMDR", "PCCSMDR");
                    bBuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(buf);
                    sock.Send(bBuf, 0, bBuf.Length, 0);     

                    data = new byte[1024];
                    recv = sock.Receive(data);
                    stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
                    textBox4.AppendText(stringData + "\r\n");
                    string df = "";
                    try
                    {
                        FileStream dr = new FileStream(textfileSaveLocation, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                        StreamReader fg = new StreamReader(dr);
                        df = fg.ReadToEnd();
                        fg.Dispose();
                        dr.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch (Exception dfjdfs)
                    {
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        File.Delete(textfileSaveLocation);
                    }
                    catch (Exception jhu)
                    {
                    }
                    try
                    {

                        FileStream cd = new FileStream(textfileSaveLocation, FileMode.Create);
                        StreamWriter cdf = new StreamWriter(cd);
                        cdf.WriteLine (df);
                        cdf.WriteLine (stringData);
                        cdf.Dispose();
                        cd.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch (Exception hgy)
                    {
                    }
                }
                sock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sock.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception DFGFD)
            {
            }
        }
```

I am getting my Username and Password into the text file in a strange format.
 I am not able to find out where i am missing to get the data from the machine.

Comment: And what´s the strange format?

Comment: @deviantfan formate is what i have posted above the c# code..That is the data getting dumped into the text file after executing this code..

Comment: What event calls this code? Also, get rid of the 'Application.DoEvents();' from inside the while loop.

Comment: @MartinJames Button click event calls this code..I removed the 'Application.DoEvents()' from inside the while loop

Comment: @MartinJames Why is the output in the text file is coming like that and why is the data not getting dumped?

Comment: @deviantfan do i need to change something here buf = String.Format("{0}/{1}", "SMDR", "PCCSMDR");
                    bBuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(buf);
                    sock.Send(bBuf, 0, bBuf.Length, 0);

Comment: @MartinJames I have pasted my machine Documentation for Username and password in the Post.